# Showing Boundary of a Set is Closed using \epsilon-balls

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am reviewing some real analysis, and could use some help finishing this proof shown to me a while ago that the boundary of a set is closed.

---

Suppose we have a set $E$ on a metric space $(X, d)$. We wish to show that the boundary of $E$, denoted by $\text{bdry}(E)$, is closed.

**Proof**

Let $p$ be a limit point of $\text{bdry}(E)$. Then
$$ \forall \epsilon > 0, \exists q \in \text{bdry}(E) \text{ s.t. } q \in N_{\epsilon}(p) \qquad (q \neq p) $$
where $N_{\epsilon}(p)$ is an $\epsilon$-neighborhood around $p$. (Visually, we can think of this as drawing an $\epsilon$-ball around $p$, and that it contains a point $q$ that is in the boundary of $E$.)

Now let $r = \epsilon - d(p, q)$, and it follows that $N_r(q) \subset N_{\epsilon}(p)$. (Visually, imagine drawing a smaller ball of radius $r$ that is contained inside the $\epsilon$-ball).

And here is where I am stuck. How does this show that $p \in \text{bdry}(E)$, or that the boundary is closed?

Comment: You need to prove that it's not in the interior, and that it is a limit point. You can use the fact that q is a boundary point to prove there is a point outside E near it, to prove p isn't in the interior. And you know p is contained in the closure of E, as it is a limit of points in the closure of E.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E'$ denote the boundary of $E$. Then:
$$p \in E' \iff \forall \epsilon > 0: N_{\epsilon}(p) \cap E \neq \varnothing \land N_{\epsilon}(p) \cap E^c \neq \varnothing$$
In other words, every $\epsilon$ nbhd of $p$ intersects both $E$ and $E^c$. Since $N_r(q) \subseteq N_{\epsilon}(p)$ and since $q \in E'$, it follows that $N_r(q)$ intersects $E$ and $E^c$. But this implies that $N_{\epsilon}(p)$ intersects $E$ and $E^c$. So, that proves that $p$ lies in the boundary as well.

Comment: Thanks! It was not so obvious visually, but from the definition of boundary the logic became clear.